# convert dictionary of dictionaries using its key as index in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have this dictionary of dictionaries,

```
# dic
{ 1:
   { URL : "www.sample.com",
     elements: ["foo", "bar", .....]
   },
  2:
   { URL: "www. ..... "
     elements: ["hello", "world",...]
   }
}
```

and I want to convert it to pandas dataframe.

```
df = pd.Dataframe([(k, k1, v1) for k, v in dic.item() for k1, v1 in v.items()], columns=['index', 'URL', 'elements'])

# it returns 
   index   URL             elements
0    1     URL          www.sample.com
1    1    elements      ["foo", "bar", .....]
```

But I want to this dataframe,

```
index      URL                   elements
  1       www.sample.com        ["foo", "bar", .....]
  2       www. .....            ["hello", "world",...]
```

I am feeling I am close, but cannot make more progress. Can anyone point out where I did wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call the `pd.DataFrame()` method on your dictionary and transpose using [`.T`](https://www.w3resource.com/pandas/dataframe/dataframe-t.php) it to the way you want it to look.

Then reset the index using [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
In [1092]: df = pd.DataFrame(dic).T.reset_index()                                                                                                                                                             

In [1093]: df                                                                                                                                                                                               
Out[1093]: 
   index             URL        elements
0      1  www.sample.com      [foo, bar]
1      2     www. .....   [hello, world]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas built-in method `pd.DataFrame.from_dict()` and then reset the index.

Starting with your dictionary:

```
di = { 1:
   { "URL" : "www.sample.com",
     "elements": ["foo", "bar"]
   },
  2:
   { "URL": "www. ..... ",
     "elements": ["hello", "world"]
   }
}
```

Using the `from_dict()` and `reset_index()` methods:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(di, orient='index').reset_index()
```

Results in:

```
   index             URL        elements
0      1  www.sample.com      [foo, bar]
1      2     www. .....   [hello, world]
```